# How to despose data into a v-data-table by index?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Im new with vue and i was trying to dispose data from a rest api using axios to make requests but i the data came as object or promise and i tryed alot things but doesn work

the data came as JSON like this:

{
"AglomeradosSubnormais2010_Limites.sld": "http://api/styles/AglomeradosSubnormais2010_Limites.sld",
"AglomeradosSubnormais2010_Limites.xml": "http://api/styles/AglomeradosSubnormais2010_Limites.xml",

"Agricultura_Irrigada.sld": "http://api/styles/ccar/Agricultura_Irrigada.sld",
 ...
}

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid fill-height>
    <v-card height='100%'>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="styleList"
        class="elevation-1"
      >
        <template v-slot:index="props">
          <td>{{ props.index }}</td>
          <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
            <v-icon class="mr-2" @click="editItem(props.item)">
              remove_red_eye
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
              get_app
            </v-icon>
          </td>
        </template>
        <template v-slot:no-data>
          <v-alert :value="true" color="error" icon="warning">
            Error
          </v-alert>
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="search">Atualizar</v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

```
data() {
      return {
        styleList: [],
      }
}
computed: {
      async search() {
          const response = await this.request('url') 
          this.styleList = response.data
          return this.styleList
       }
    },
```

then i got alot os errors:

[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object

[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "items": "TypeError: this.items.map is not a function"

[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function"

TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The `v-data-table` prop `items` is waiting for an array. But you gave him an object : `styleList`. You should parse the `response.data` to only get an array. To help you do that we'll need more info about this `response.data`.

Comment: the response.data is the json that is at the top of the question.